# Transaction for multiple saves, and does a rollback if any one of the model is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, rollback

I'm doing this app in Ruby on Rails, and basically my view has this form which sends a nested `params` with multiple information, something like this:

```
"attributes"=>
[<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>1, "date"=>"2010-10-13"} permitted: true>, 
 <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>8, "date"=>"2020-12-07"} permitted: true>],
 ... // Imagine there being alot of parameters... } permitted: true>, ...
```

So what I wanna do is create Models with these parameters and then save it to my database. However, as long as one of these models is invalid, I want to do a rollback so that none of these are saved to the database, and then I proceed to return some error message which I can display on my view to tell the user where did they go wrong etc.

My code looks something like this:

```
 @params_list = params["attributes"]
 Item.transaction do
      @params_list.each do |item_params|
        @item = Item.new(
            id: item_params["id"],
            date: item_params["date"]
        )

      next if @item.save!

      else 
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback # Since if it is invalid, it would not be saved to the database
????
Kinda lost at this part already
```

Was wondering is there a faster way to do this? Am I doing this right, and if this is the wrong design and I should be changing how this works?

PS, my first time working with ruby on rails so I'm pretty lost, and would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're using `save!`, you don't need the else and raise. `save!` raises an error if the record is invalid and that will rollback the transaction. This is exactly the right way to do this.

You will need to rescue the `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` somewhere though and render a proper error message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of hashes to the `create!` method.

```
Item.transaction do  
  Item.create!([
    { title: 'first title' }, 
    { title: 'second title'} 
  ]) 
end
```

In your example:

```
Item.transaction do  
  bulk_params = params["attributes"].map{ |item| item.slice(:id, :date) }
  Item.create!(bulk_params)
end
```

**Note 1**: (!) at end of `create` will raise Exception if the creating at least one record fails and all operation will be rollbacked since the create operation in transition block.

**Note 2**: This is not a bulk operation and the performance will be the same as creating one by one.

**Rails(6+)**:
If you want to insert as a bulk operation, you can use [insert_all](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all), **but this will not instantiate any models and does not call Active Record callbacks or validations**.

```
Item.insert_all([
  { title: 'first title' }, 
  { title: 'second title'} 
])
```